# php, jquery - post login to the same page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

I just created little login system, but there is some ubelievable problem with it. Sometimes it logs in, sometimes not.

Loging in is done by this code:

```
if(isset($_POST['logedOut'])) {
    setcookie('username', '', time() - 3600);
    setcookie('userid', '', time() - 3600);
    $logedIn = false;
} else if(isset($_POST['logedIn'])) {
    echo 'POST SENT';
    $expire = ($_POST['remember'] == true) ? time() + $GLOBALS['year'] : '';
    setcookie('username', $_POST['logedIn'], $expire);
    setcookie('userid', $_POST['id'], $expire);
    $username = $_POST['logedIn'];
    $userid = $_POST['id'];
    $logedIn = true;
} else if (isset($_COOKIE['username'])) {
    $logedIn = true;
    $username = $_COOKIE['username'];
    $userid = $_COOKIE['userid'];
} else {
    echo 'POST NOT SENT';
    $logedIn = false;
}
```

For ease:

```
    if(isset($_POST['logedIn'])) { 
        echo 'POST SENT';
        $logedIn = true;
    }  else {
        echo 'POST NOT SENT';
        $logedIn = false;
    }
```

Inside of javascript i have call

```
function checkUser (mail, pass, rem) {
    var sectionName = 'checkUser';
    $.ajax({
        async: true,
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'php/readDB.php',
        cache: false,
        contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
        data: {section: sectionName, email: mail, password: pass, remember: rem},
        dataType: 'text',
        timeout: 3000,
        beforeSend: function() {
            console.log('Read from DB called');
        },
        success: function(data) {   
            if(data!='false') {
                $('<form action="#" method="post"><input type="hidden" name="logedIn" value="' + mail + '" /><input type="hidden" name="remember" value="' + rem + '" /><input type="hidden" name="id" value="' + data + '" /></form>').appendTo('body').submit();
            } else {
                $('#afterDialog').html('Uživatelské jméno nebo heslo je špatně zadáno.');
                $('#afterDialog').dialog('open');
            }                                   
        },
        error: function(request, errorType, errorMessage) {
            alert('Error: ' + errorType + ' with message: ' + errorMessage);
        },
        complete: function() {
            console.log('Read from DB completed');
        }       
    });
}
```

Each time I fill form and click button, this function is called and in each case, if form is filled right, it goes to $('...').submit();, but in 90% of tryings no POST data are transfered and PHP page echoes "POST NOT SENT". In 10% is user loged succesfully (with same input data in login form (mail, pass, rem). So, any idea, where problem can be?

Comment: Observation: If i comment line with .submit(), reload page and try to login it still working, like that line is uncommented. It's like some kind of caching or what.

Comment: Where do you pass `$_POST['logedIn']` to your PHP?

Comment: "Where do you pass $_POST['logedIn'] to your PHP?" On 17th line of javascript code above.

Comment: New observation, setcookie() creating cookies very randomly. Rather no than yes.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/b6wUXT9U Always go throught echo $res['id']; (line21), but never creates cookies (line 19,20)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally, i had it, problem was in jQuery UI dialog. It's difference between press Enter after fill up form or click on dialog's button "Login". Now I need to bind form's Enter press to jqueryui's dialog button.